# Check the attribute of sub-element is with in the range of ancestor:elements attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, schematron

I am new to schematron and 
trying to write an assertion that will verify the values of  @Origin and @end of 'tests' nodes with in the range of @Origin and @end of 'bases'

I have tried the assertion as below but it is not working.

```
<sch:rule context="test">
  <sch:assert test="End[*]/@value &gt; ancestor::bases/bound/End/@value and Origin[*]/@value &lt; ancestor::bases/bound/Origin/@value " >values are within range. </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

```xml
<tests_root>
    <bases>
        <bound x="-276.724" xEnd="-276.193">
            <Origin value="1"/>
            <End value="20"/>
        </bound>
    </bases>
    <tests>
        <test x="-276.724" xEnd="-276.193">
            <Origin value="1"/>
            <End value="2"/>
        </test>
        <test x="-276.193" xEnd="-260.29">
            <Origin value="2"/>
            <End value="5"/>
        </test>
        <test x="-260.29" xEnd="-240.194">
            <Origin value="5"/>
            <End value="10"/>
        </test>
        <test x="-240.194" xEnd="-220.046">
            <Origin value="10"/>
            <End value="19"/>
        </test>
        <test x="-220.046" xEnd="-200.09">
            <Origin value="19"/>
            <End value="20"/>
        </test>
    </tests>
</tests_root>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things aren't correct in your Schematron, the main being that `ancestor::bases/bound/End/@value` won't match any node because `<bases>` is **not** an ancestor of `<test>`. Using `/tests_root/bases/bound/End/@value` will retrieve the value you want.

Then it seems you implemented the `<sch:assert>` rule in the way opposite (and incomplete because you're not testing the bound values for both the Origin and End) you enounced it. To remind:

- an `assert` will raise a message if the test in not true;
- a `report` will raise a message if the test is true.

As a hint, you can use `<sch:let>` that will improve readability of your code:

This is the way I would implement your controls:

```
<sch:pattern>
    <sch:let name="min-origin" value="number(/tests_root/bases/bound/Origin/@value)"/>
    <sch:let name="max-end" value="number(/tests_root/bases/bound/End/@value)"/>

    <sch:rule context="test/End | test/Origin">
        <sch:assert test="@value &lt;= $max-end and @value &gt;= $min-origin" ><sch:name/>/@value is not within the allowed range [<sch:value-of select="$min-origin"/>,<sch:value-of select="$max-end"/>]. </sch:assert>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```